# Why Netbeans 6.8 remote project (php) uploads all files by default

Tags: php, netbeans

Hi I wanted to know if there's some option for disabling Netbeans to upload all files of a recently imported remote (php) project.

I always check "Upload files on run", in the project configuration. But when I click on run Netbeans selects all files by default (I modified only some). The file checkboxes cannot be disabled at once and you have to do this one by one (imagine you have 5000 files...). That's annoying.

Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... there is a "uncheck all" option if you right-click somewhere on the list, then you can use the search function to track down the files you modified then check those. Next time Netbeans will upload just the modified files, at least that always worked for me.

Comment: Hehe I didn't realized that. Thank you It worked :)

Comment: +1 just had this happen to me... The option is now a checkbox, but the solution is the same.  However, I need to emphasize that you need to have **at least one thing checked to upload**; otherwise, next time Netbeans will try to upload everything again!